# Tab Bar Item is a grey square

Tags: ios, iphone

As you can see, instead of an image there is just a big grey square. I have an image in my asset-catalog and I've set it through the attributes inspector. The image is 50x50px, and I read in documentation that it could be of any size but not bigger than 96x96. Screenshot below.

[image]

Thank you!

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/02KJj.png):

Answer (score 1):

There is bug in iOS7 and the unselected tab bar item is always with grey tint color.

Try this: (add in AppDelegate application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:)

```
    UITabBarItem *item1 = self.tabBarController.tabBar.items[0];
    item1.image = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"tabbar-item1"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal]; // unselected image
    item1.selectedImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"tabbar-item1-selected"]; // selected image

    UITabBarItem *item2 ...
    ...
```

Comment: Is the tabBarController the root or should I access each ViewController connected to the tab view?

Comment: _tabBarController is UITabBarController