# The tab bar item image lost the color

Tags: ios7

In the AppDelegate.m, I select the golden picture as the image for the tab bar item. While, when the app run, the tab bar item image turns gray, and blue when selected.

```
UITabBar *tabBar = tabBarController.tabBar;

UITabBarItem *exhitibionItem    = [tabBar.items objectAtIndex:0];

[exhitibionItem setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"GoldenPicture.png"]];
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer here.
[Tab Bar Item is a grey square](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19841858/tab-bar-item-is-a-grey-square#)

```
[exhitibionItem setImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"GoldenPicture.png"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal]];
```